# gazebo_gui missing icons in fuerte

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The gazebo gui is missing the icons to play/pause, create new boxes, etc.

Maybe this has something to do with the warning I get:

**libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.46 but running with 1.5.4**

I don't quite understand this, since I have libpng12-dev version 1.2.46-3ubuntu1.3 installed.

I also get a debug message, but it is probably unrelated to the icon problem:
**Dbg pluginPaths and GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH doesn't exist.Set GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH to Ogre's installation path. ...or are you loading via SystemPlugins?**

I launched gazebo via *roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch*

I understand this is not the final release of fuerte yet, but it seemed best to use ros answers to "report" this issue.

Version/system details:

- Ubuntu oneiric x86_64
- Lenovo T420 with Intel sandy bridge mobile graphics (or nVidia NVS 4200M optimus)
- installed ros-fuerte-desktop-full
- ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo 1.6.5-s1333786104~oneiric

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31946/gazebo_gui-missing-icons-in-fuerte/) by [Felix Ruess](https://answers.ros.org/users/890/felix-ruess/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2012-04-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After upgrading to precise everything is fine, no warning and icons are there again.
I can't check anymore, but I probably somehow ended up with an additional libpng previously.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Ruess](https://answers.ros.org/users/890/felix-ruess/) with karma: 118 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) on 2012-05-13**:
I just faced the same problem. Could you please explain what exactly you have upgraded? I have checked, I have libpng12-0 and libpng12-dev installed

**Comment by [Felix Ruess](https://answers.ros.org/users/890/felix-ruess/) on 2012-05-30**:
I'm now running Ubuntu Precise 12.04 with the normal ubuntu packages built for precise and it works there. But I don't know what exactly was the issue on Ubuntu Oneiric....